# How can I parameterise Azure's TableOperation.Retrieve<TElement> in a method in c# .NET

Tags: c#, azure, tdd, azure-storage, microsoft-fakes

I have a class, something like the following:

```
public class Table : ITable
    {
        private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        public Table()
        {
            var storageAccountSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageConnection"].ToString();
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountSettings);
        }
        public async Task<TableResult> Retrieve(string tableReference, string partitionKey, string rowKey)
        {
            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableReference);
            TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SomeDomainModelType>(partitionKey, rowKey);
            TableResult retrievedResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
            return retrievedResult;
        }
    }
```

This class is a wrapper to retrieve a single entity from an Azure table. It's wrapped up and conforms to an interface so that it can be stubbed out with Microsoft Fakes during testing. It works at the moment, however it would be more elegant if the following was more generic:

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SomeDomainModelType>(partitionKey, rowKey);
```

My question is how can I parameterise `<SomeDomainModelType>` so that I can use the method with any type in the domain model ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the [C# Programming Guide on Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), specifically the [Generic Methods](http://Generic%20Methods) section. Basically, define a Generic Method that can take an ITableEntity:

```
    public async Task<TableResult> Retrieve<T>(string tableReference, string partitionKey, string rowKey) where T : ITableEntity
    {
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableReference);
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        TableResult retrievedResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
        return retrievedResult;
    }
```

Comment: This works well, nice one :) Although I have another problem now trying to work out how to stub out a generic in Microsoft Fakes. I've submitting a separate question for that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307972/how-to-stub-out-a-generic-method-definition-in-an-interface-using-microsoft-fake :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can return retrievedResult.Result as an entity directly:

```
    public async Task<TEntity> Retrieve<TEntity>(string tableReference, string partitionKey, string rowKey) : where TEntity : ITableEntity
    {
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableReference);
        TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<TEntity>(partitionKey, rowKey);
        TableResult retrievedResult = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
        return (TEntity)retrievedResult.Result;
    }
```

Comment: Good to know :) But in my case I wanted the whole TableResult because my API layer is checking that the query on the Azure table is giving a http status code 200, i.e. I have condition code on TableResult.HttpStatusCode.

Comment: If so, you can customize your own generic TableResult<TEntity> class to make the return type generic as well and avoid type conversion out of the Retrieve method. :)

Comment: Right now if I get a http status code 200 I simply convert retrievedResult.Result to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json. This seems to work fine. Would recommend a custom generic TableResult<TEntity> for this? Is there any gain in this case?

Comment: No much gain, just to keep the method aligned with generic programming.

Comment: Cool, I guess I'll stick without the custom generic at the moment because what I have meets my requirements. Maybe I'll implement if need be at a later date :)

Comment: After implementing this stuff I've realized that a custom TableResult<TEntity> would be very useful in creating a solid unit test, i.e. I could make sure the returning TableResult<TEntity> was the type I was expecting rather than just an Object returned by the regular TableResult.Result. Do you know of any examples showing how this can be done? Maybe I should post a separate question for this?

Comment: You have to define your own TableResult<TEntity> class and construct its instance as the return value of this method since TableResult<TEntity> doesn't exist in the client library.