# How to stub out a generic method definition in an interface using Microsoft Fakes in c#

Tags: unit-testing, generics, mocking, microsoft-fakes, stubbing

I have a unit test which stubs out the following interface using Microsoft Fakes:

```
public interface ITable
{
    Task<TableResult> Retrieve(string tableReference, string partitionKey, string rowKey);
}
```

The stub looks like this:

```
ITable table = new MessagesAPI.Azure.Fakes.StubITable()
            {
                RetrieveStringStringString = delegate
                  {
                      TableResult tableResult = new TableResult();
                      return Task.FromResult(tableResult);
                  }
            };
```

This works fine. However I'd like to change the interface to be more generic like so:

```
public interface ITable
{
    Task<TableResult> Retrieve<T>(string tableReference, string partitionKey, string rowKey) 
                     where T : ITableEntity;
}
```

Question is how would I stub this new version of the interface out? I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the behavior as the following:

```
var table = new MessagesAPI.Azure.Fakes.StubITable();

table.RetrieveOf1StringStringString<ITableEntity>(
     (tableReference, partitionKey, rowKey) =>
{
    TableResult tableResult = new TableResult();
    return Task.FromResult(tableResult);
});
```